# Why I can't get disconnected when another app connected to chromecast?

Tags: ios, chromecast

When my ios app connected to chromecast and play stream music and I use youtube app to connect same chromecast but my app can't get disconnect notification?

Comment: Is YouTube app launched or it just connectes?

Comment: When your app stops or when you get disconnected, you do receive call backs to that effect. You need to make sure you are registered for receiving the appropriate events.

Comment: You can implement disconnection on your own: generate a message from receiver to sender through custom channel